# React-Native build App on Emulator works - real device not

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

If I build my App it works on my Android Emulator. If I use my real android device ( Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge) it also build, but uses an old version of my app. On the Emulator the newest version is always deployed. Do you know why? I don't get an error or sth. I want a debug apk.

I already tried to unistall the old version. 
I already tried to ./gradlew assembleDebug

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you using it for dev or prod? Have you tried uninstalling older version? What have you tried in general, please describe.

Comment: Sorry! I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing the debug version on your device (not bundling for release) then that is expected.

You need to "shake" your device in order to enter the RN dev menu and choose refresh. That should trigger the on demand bundling again.

If this is not the case, then please post your errors, code, logs, etc.